# How to add record to Azure Table Storage from Azure Functions with binding?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I user those and run Azure Functions at local environment.

> Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.3)
>
> Function Runtime Version:2.0.12115.0
>
> azurite@2.7.0

I try as Microsoft document says.
Here is functions.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "input",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "tableName": "Person",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "name": "tableBinding",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Here is local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

Here is index.js

```
module.exports = function (context) {

    context.bindings.tableBinding = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        context.bindings.tableBinding.push({
            PartitionKey: "Test",
            RowKey: i.toString(),
            Name: "Name " + i
        });
    }

    context.done();
};
```

Installed extensions with this.

```
$ func extensions install -p Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage --version 3.0.0
```

Run functions from mac terminal, Send http request, I got this error.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.test. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling
>   parameter _binder after function returned:.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Not Implemented (HTTP
>   status code 501: . ). Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Not Implemented.

Error from Table Storage

> POST /devstoreaccount1/$batch 501 0.980 ms - 45

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UseDevelopmentStorage=true` represents function is set to use [Storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#get-the-storage-emulator), which provides a local environment that emulates the Azure Storage Blob, Queue and Table services for development purposes. But unfortunately it's only available on OS Windows, so you got `Not Implemented` on Mac.

Workaround is to use a real world Storage account, follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-manage?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#view-and-copy-access-keys) to get the Connection string, if you don't have a Storage account you may have to [create one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-quickstart-create-account?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=portal) first.

One more suggestion is [install](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#mac) latest Azure Functions Core Tools, right now it's 2.1.725.

Comment: With actual Storage account, it worked! I wish it could use emulator though, but thanks.